# Can't create audio data with Google cloud-text-to-speech using php client library. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, text-to-speech, google-cloud-sdk

I have used the quickstart instructions on:
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-php to set up a Google Cloud Platform project on ubuntu 16.04 to create speech from text using php.

I believe I have successfully completed all the instructions:

- enabled the text to speech API
- set up authentication created service account key
- set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the path of the key file and verifed that by entering
  `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` at the command line.
- installed the Cloud SDK, run gcloud init and got no errors
- installed the library with `composer require google/cloud-text-to-speech`

Now, when I try to run the example php code...

```
// includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Imports the Cloud Client Library
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SsmlVoiceGender;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

// instantiates a client
$client = new TextToSpeechClient();

// sets text to be synthesised
$synthesisInputText = (new SynthesisInput())
    ->setText('Hello, world!');

// build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
// voice gender
$voice = (new VoiceSelectionParams())
    ->setLanguageCode('en-US')
    ->setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender::FEMALE);

// Effects profile
$effectsProfileId = "telephony-class-application";

// select the type of audio file you want returned
$audioConfig = (new AudioConfig())
    ->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::MP3)
    ->setEffectsProfileId(array($effectsProfileId));

// perform text-to-speech request on the text input with selected voice
// parameters and audio file type
$response = $client->synthesizeSpeech($synthesisInputText, $voice, $audioConfig);
$audioContent = $response->getAudioContent();

// the response's audioContent is binary
file_put_contents('output.mp3', $audioContent);
echo 'Audio content written to "output.mp3"' . PHP_EOL;
```

... I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DomainException: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information in /var/www/my-domain/folder/vendor/google/auth/src/ApplicationDefaultCredentials.php:168

If I use the command line to create the audio, it works fine, so the account, authorisation and the SDK would appear to be configured correctly.

It is the first time I have used GCP, so I fully expect I'm missing something obvious. Help much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Problem solved by adding:

`putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key/key.json');`

after importing the cloud library and before instantiating the client object.

Comment: All looks good. Before I try to repro, did you `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`?

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for your comment. I have added an edit above with the solution that I found to work. To answer your question, yes I did try export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS which worked when running the command line script to create audio, but not for the client library.

Comment: You're welcome. Curious. `putenv` should have the equivalent behavior to bash `export`.

Comment: can you play the generated audio files? I can get the file, but can't play them